# Why is my HttpPostedFileBase always null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

It looks similar to other questions but all problem they had was naming mismatch between name of input type="file" in HTML and name of parameter in controller. I have checked and rechecked many things many times, but still the value of HttpPostedFileBase is always returning as null which is causing NullReferenceException in controller.
Here is the code:-
HTML CODE:-

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
     {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Please Fill in the following details and Upload your Design Pic</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.chest)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.chest)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chest)
    </div>
    <p>
        <label for="file">Design File Pic:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Order" />
    </p>
```

In Controller:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(DesignOrder order, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string fileurl=null;
        if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
            fileurl = Path.Combine("../../Images/UserUploads",User.Identity.Name + file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(fileurl); 
        }
    }
```

Error comes in line if(file.ContentLength>0) -- NullreferenceException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Html.BeginForm(object)` is for `RouteValues`, not element attributes. You need to use the bigger overload for attributes. Try this:

```
Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

See here for what I mean: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470793(v=vs.108).aspx